# PowerShell to Replace File Text using DataSet

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to do some value substitution in PowerShell. I have a text file that contains a generic query, i.e.

```
-- query.sql
SELECT
     'varTableName' AS myTableName
    , COUNT(DISTINCT parmColumnName) AS myDistinctCount
    , SUM(parmColumnName2) AS mySum
FROM varDatabaseName.varSchemaName.varTableName WITH (NOLOCK);
```

I'm trying to replace the "var" and "parm" values. I have two different datarows. In my script, I iterate through the first datarow and do a replacement using the row in focus. This works great. My question is with the next part. I then need to iterate through a second datarow that contains multiple rows, and perform the replace for any value that matches.

I tried, unsuccessfully, to do something like this:

```
# myScript.ps1 -- does not work 
# ...
# Code here to populate $MyDataRow 
ForEach ($MyRow In $MyDataRow) {
    [string]$Query = Get-Content query.sql  | ForEach-Object {
                            $_ -replace "varTableName", $Table `
                               -replace "varDatabaseName", $MyRow.DatabaseName `
                               -replace "varSchemaName", $MyRow.SchemaName `
                               -replace "varTableName", $MyRow.TableName
                               -replace $MyOtherDataRow.SearchString, $MyOtherDataRow.ReplaceString
                            }
}
```

This, however, worked:

```
# myScript.ps1 -- works
# ...
# Code here to populate $MyDataRow 
ForEach ($MyRow In $MyDataRow) {
    [string]$Query = Get-Content query.sql  | ForEach-Object {
                            $_ -replace "varTableName", $Table `
                               -replace "varDatabaseName", $MyRow.DatabaseName `
                               -replace "varSchemaName", $MyRow.SchemaName `
                               -replace "varTableName", $MyRow.TableName
                            }

    ForEach($MyOtherRow In $MyOtherDataRow) {
        $Query = $Query | ForEach-Object {
            $_ -replace $MyOtherRow.SearchString, $MyOtherRow.ReplaceString
            }
    }
}
```

I'm just learning PowerShell, though, so I don't know if this is the most efficient way of handling this. I'm wondering if I can somehow pipe this second ForEach replace to the first result? What's the best approach?

Oh, and in case it's relevant, I'm using PowerShell 3.0.

Any input is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do it like this:

```
$query = Get-Content query.sql

$MyDataRow | % {
  $query = $query -replace "varDatabaseName", $_.DatabaseName `
                  -replace "varSchemaName", $_.SchemaName `
                  -replace "varTableName", $_.TableName
}

$MyOtherDataRow | % {
  $query = $query -replace $_.SearchString, $_.ReplaceString
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ansgar! I appreciate your response. :)